# Why does subprocess.call(['python', argsStr]) fail both with or without shell=True?

Tags: python, subprocess

So, I have a legacy script `ts`, that I need to call in a loop using several string arguments:

```
#User supplied
ts = '/d1/user/script.py'
adir = '/d1/user/adir'
mfile = '/d1/user/script.nc'
outdir = '/d1/user/park/'

metens = glob.glob(adir + '/*.nc')  #reads all files

for count, value in enumerate(metens):
    runcom = [ts, mfile, metens[count], outdir + os.path.basename(metens[count])]   
    runcom = " ".join(runcom) #This creates a string of CL arguments
    subprocess.call(['python2.7', runcom], shell=True)
```

Now, when I run it, it calls python2.7 and opens the Python shell instead of running it as `python2.7 runcom`.

How can I make it run as a script instead of opening the shell?

Comment: is `ts` code or a file path?

Comment: @JorgeLeitão I have added more info. ts is a file.

Comment: Remove the argument `shell=True`? If I run `python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['python2.7', 'test.py'])"` it tells me that the file does not exist and exits 1. If I create that file and run again, it runs the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I removed the `shell=True`, And I am getting ` [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Even though all the necessary files exists. If I just copy paste the python2.7 runcom to a command line directly, it works. So nothing is wrong with the program..

Comment: Maybe having a string of arguments changes the behavior?

Comment: If you use `shell=True` and pass a list, then the first list item is the only thing treated as a shell script (subsequent elements of the list are arguments to that script -- ie. its `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc), which is why they're ignored when the script doesn't refer to them.

Comment: Anyhow -- if without `shell=True` you get a "No such file or directory" thrown by the Python interpreter, the plain reading of that error is that `python2.7` isn't in any directory in your PATH. Determine the location of that executable, determine what the value of `os.environ['PATH']` is at the point of execution of the code that fails, etc.

Comment: ("plain reading" may not be the only reading -- you can get an error if, say, your Python interpreter requires a shared library and it's not present in the `rpath`, `ld.so` cached locations, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directory -- but the plain reading is the place to start).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But if I construct it inside the subprocess call, it works.

Comment: ...so, I think there may be some confusion here caused by the error not being included in the question as exact quoted text. The error being thrown by the *outer* interpreter and the *inner* interpreter have two completely different causes.

Comment: `subprocess.call(['python2.7', runcom])` would cause the *inner* python interpreter to find a Python script named as the concatenation of all the arguments that went into `runcom`. That won't work for reasons that should be obvious (those arguments aren't actually part of the script's filename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How To Fix It

```
args = ['script.py', 'first argument', 'second argument']
subprocess.call(['python2.7'] + args)
```

- Don't use `shell=True`
- Pass each argument as a separate list item; don't concatenate them into a string.

---

#### Why It Fails (with `shell=True`)

Let's take a simple case:

```
args = [ 'script.py', 'first argument' 'second argument' ]
args_str = ' '.join(args)
subprocess.call(['python2.7', args_str], shell=True)
```

What does this *actually do*?

```sh
# the above is the same as running this at a shell
sh -c python2.7 'script.py first argument second argument'
```

And what does *that* actually do? It runs `python2.7` with no arguments at all (as the argument list is interpreted as `$0` to the `sh -c` instance, but the script passed in the first element of the list contains only the string `python2.7` and doesn't look at its `$0` at all).

---

#### Why It Fails (without `shell=True`)

Let's take a simple case:

```
args = [ 'script.py', 'first argument' 'second argument' ]
args_str = ' '.join(args)
subprocess.call(['python2.7', args_str])
```

What does this *actually do*?

```sh
# the above is the same as running this at a shell
python2.7 'script.py first argument second argument'
```

...and what does *that* do, even if you have a `script.py` in your current directory?

```
python2.7: can't open file 'script.py first argument second argument': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why did that happen? Because you made your arguments *part of the script's filename*, and no filename with those argument values as part of its name exists.

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer doesn't directly answer my question

```
for count, value in enumerate(metens):
    subprocess.call(['python2.7', ts, mfile, metens[count], outdir + os.path.basename(metens[count]])
```

The runcom, if constructed inside the subprocess, works. But if I construct it outside, I get a no file error.

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, this gives me the desired files. Though I am sure there is a better way of doing this. I am just leaving it in till something better comes along.

Comment: No -- there isn't something better. This is the way it should be done.

Comment: (well -- you can construct it outside; what you need to avoid is condensing it down to a string, as opposed to keeping it as a list).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know know what this was working. But I got it now.